# Best way to integrate Jenkins X on to pre-existing GKE

Tags: node.js, jenkins, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, jenkins-x

I have a current GKE that runs a Node JS/React application. My project is hosted on Github and I am currently using Jenkins for my CI/CD pipeline. I have recently heard about Jenkins X and am interested in trying to use it for my GKE cluster.

On the official docs / most tutorials I seen, it mostly describes how to set up Jenkins X on a new Kubernetes cluster and a new Github repo. I'm wondering what would be the best/easiest approach to integrate Jenkins X into my current GKE & Github repo.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use Jenkins X Boot to install in your existing cluster, typically under a new `jx` namespace. Then use `jx import` to bring your existing projects under jx

Comment: I have the error that "trying to execute 'jx boot' from a non requirements repo", I can't get jx boot to run at all